# Java: How to link the methods of a few classes into one object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

I wrote a client application that has:

- Session management data types and methods (`createSession()`, `connect()`, `disconnect()`, etc...)
- Domain-Specific-Language methods for operating with the objects handled by the server (`createVM()`, `startVM()`, etc...)
- Local data preparation (`formatDataForVmTypeA()`, `extractValueFromResponse()`, etc...)

My problem is that it's all in one class: OldStyleClient

A. It's too much code for one file - hard for me to find things, even though I wrote everything in there
B. I want to lift some of the code into it's own object, so I can do some OO stuff on an encapsulated part of the Client.

In my crazy imagination, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
import ClientSession;  // Backbone of the client data and methods (session handling, etc...)
import ClientDSL;      // contains doThis(); method
import ClientChecks;   // contains checkRC(); method

ClientSession currentSession = new ClientSession();
currentSession.doThis();
currentSession.checkRC();
```

I've heard I could use interfaces to achieve a many-to-one inheritance but I think interfaces are not
my best bet: their prime goal seems to be to create some code-level contracts for when programmers write a class that needs to talk to another class - and multiple inheritance is merely a side-effect.

Is there a way to somehow tell Java something like "I want the methods from 'ClientDSL' to be applicable on 'ClientSession' objects?

Also, what is the correct name of the problem I am trying to solve (in order for me to search for solutions better)?

Comment: You could make an interface for all the methods in ClientDSL, implement them in ClientDSL, and then in your ClientSession class you also implement the interface, but for all those methods you just make it call the ClientDSL's methods

Comment: So, if I add a new DSL method, do I need to add a stub with the same signature in every class that implements the interface or just update my interface (that one class)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces (so that you can implement more than one!) and [default methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/) (Java 8 onwards) so that you won't have to implement the methods in the class that implements them.

Comment: Hi, I tried reading about the concepts you mentioned but wasn't able to get what I wanted. Care to share some code to give me a direction? Doesn't have to compile, just enough so I see where to put what, thanks! :)